# Converting Sequence in Oracle to Identity in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I'm trying to recreate some tables originally in oracle to a new database in Azure Data Studio (MSSQL) and having trouble with sequences. I was able to create all of the sequences in use but found out after the fact that they can't be used in table creation like they can in Oracle and I'm now not sure how to create the tables.

How would I recreate this in MSSQL with identities if sequences can't be used in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements?

Example originally from Oracle attempted in MSSQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_Example MINVALUE 1 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE Example
(
    ADDRESS_ID  NUMBER DEFAULT SEQ_Example.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(250),
    CITY        VARCHAR2(250),
    STATE       VARCHAR2(50),
);
```

Error received in Azure:

> The name "SEQ_Example.NEXTVAL" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are     constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

EDIT:
This ended up being the way I did it, thanks to the responses here:

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    ADDRESS_ID  NUMBER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(250),
    CITY        VARCHAR2(250),
    STATE       VARCHAR2(50),
);
```

Comment: SQL Server has SEQUENCE objects too. You don't need `IDENTITY()`, you need to fix the error. That's not how you specify a default value

Comment: that said: identity is preferred over sequence

Comment: I suggest you search and read a few articles, it's not complicated: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-identity/

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-sequence/

Comment: The MSSQL table with converted data types and syntax should be like `CREATE TABLE Example(ADDRESS_ID  int DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_Example NOT NULL, ADDRESS VARCHAR(250),  CITY VARCHAR(250), STATE VARCHAR(50), );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL ISO standard use the expression "NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence_name>" to give a new value in place of the DEFAULT constraint into the column definition and MS SQL Server conforms to the standard.

An other way to do this is to use the IDENTITY property like :

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
ADDRESS_ID  int NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
ADDRESS     VARCHAR(250),  
CITY        VARCHAR(250), 
STATE       VARCHAR(50),
... )
```

In this case, MS SQL Server does not conforms to the standard by the fact that IDENTITY way invented years ago by Sybase (in the early 80's)